# What are UITextStorageDirection and UITextLayoutDirection enums in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Can someone explain what is `UITextStorageDirection` and `UITextLayoutDirection` in `UIKit` framework of Apple, since there is not much documentation explaining what these 2 enums are, and what are the differences between them?

Also, I would like to see some example on text string, what does these 2 enums represent in a given text?

Comment: Refer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput?language=objc

Comment: I know, I've looked into it already, but their documentation does not explain these two classes, and the difference between the two, like when to use the one, and when the other?

Comment: You are confusing enums for classes. Those two are enums. From what I gather with a quick look it's for dealing with languages that are written right to left like Urdu, or top to bottom like ancient Chinese text. Rest you can tinkle around. And maybe put your finding on a blog ;)

Comment: Ok, thank you, now something makes a little bit more sense. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [UITextStorageDirection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextstoragedirection) :- The direction of text storage.

Sets a value that controls whether the cursor is displayed at the start of the last line or end of the second-to-last line of a multiline selection.

For text selections that wrap across line boundaries, this property determines whether the insertion point appears after the last character on the line or before the first character on the following line. The selection affinity is set in response to the user navigating via the keyboard (for example, command-right-arrow). The text input system checks this property when it moves the insertion point around in a document.
- Case

```
UITextStorageDirection.backward
```

```
UITextStorageDirection.forward
```

### [UITextLayoutDirection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextlayoutdirection?language=objc) :- The direction of text layout.

The method is currently a bit buggy, since it does not take
UITextLayoutDirectionUp and UITextLayoutDirectionDown into account.

This patch is mostly for fixing something "just in case", since
we so far have not seen UIKit calling this method for those
directions unless a hardware keyboard is connected. And in
that case, we anyway override IM navigation by dealing
with the arrow keys explicit.

Since IM in Qt does not support getting the position above
or below the current position, we just return the current
position, making it a no-op.

> Metadata ID

```
UIKit.UITextView.position(within: UIKit.UITextRange, farthestIn: UIKit.UITextLayoutDirection)
```

### Get cursor position

```
if let selectedRange = textView.selectedTextRange {

    let cursorPosition = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.start)

    print("\(cursorPosition)")
}
```

### Set cursor position

In order to set the position, all of these methods are actually setting a range with the same start and end values.

**To the beginning**

```
let newPosition = textView.beginningOfDocument
textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRange(from: TextPosition, to: TextPosition)
```

**To the end**

```
let newPosition = textView.endOfDocument
textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRangeFromPosition(newPosition, toPosition: newPosition)
```

**To one position to the left of the current cursor position**

```
// only if there is a currently selected range
if let selectedRange = textView.selectedTextRange {

    // and only if the new position is valid
    if let newPosition = textView.position(from: selectedRange.start in: UITextLayoutDirection.Left, offset: 1) {

        // set the new position
        textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRange(from: TextPosition, to: TextPosition)
    }
}
```

**To an arbitrary position**

Start at the beginning and move 5 characters to the right.

```
let arbitraryValue: Int = 5
if let newPosition = 
textView.position(from: textView.beginningOfDocument in: UITextLayoutDirection.Right, offset: arbitraryValue) {

    textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRange(from: TextPosition, to: TextPosition)
}
```

Comment: What is text storage and what is text layout? What is the difference between them? Can you give it in an example text, like: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

Comment: Updated Now check